# Spring @Transactional - javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: spring, jta, spring-aop, transactional

In the following schema

Controller -> Service -> DAO I'm trying to make Service operations @Transactional

in my UserService.fooFunction() i call

```
Entity e = dao.find(key)
e.setProperty(something)
dao.update(e)
```

in dao.update(e) at the end there is

```
em.flush() //EntityManager obtained by @PersistenceContext annotation (injected by spring IoC)
```

Calling flush() throws a persistenceException:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(JTATransactionWrapper.java:86)
```

I'm running low on ideas what I've done wrong, any help would be appreciated :)

You can find chunks of my configuration below:

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" id="eclipselinkVendorAdapter">
        ..
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">

</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

aop part:

```
    <aop:config>

    <aop:pointcut id="userServiceOperation"
      expression="execution(* org.mypackage.UserServiceImpl.*(..))"/>

    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="userServiceOperation" advice-ref="txUserServiceAdvice"/>

</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txUserServiceAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

no transactional annotations are present. When deploying my spring app one can see

```
[<date>] DEBUG support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
[<date>] DEBUG interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource: Adding transactional method [get*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly]
[<date>] DEBUG interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource: Adding transactional method [update*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
[<date>] DEBUG interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource: Adding transactional method [*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_MANDATORY,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
```

Answer (score 4):

Key problem was here

> tx:annotation-driven only looks for
>   @Transactional on beans in the same
>   application context it is defined in.
>   This means that, if you
>   put in a
>   WebApplicationContext for a
>   DispatcherServlet, it only checks for
>   @Transactional beans in your
>   controllers, and not your services.
>   See Section 15.2, “The
>   DispatcherServlet” for more
>   information.

Putting  i the same application context as component-scan for services solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You declared `JtaTransactionManager` as your transaction manager. Are you sure your program is running in JTA-capable environment, such as a full-blown application server (JBoss, WebSphere, WebLogic, etc)?

If you don't have JTA environment, you need to use `JPATransactionManager` instead:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes - I'm running this app on Sun's Glassfish app server. I consider my problem solved :)  Thank you for your reply!