# TransactionRequiredException in spring webmvc framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

It's many similar, but not the same issues, so I couldn't find a solution for this one.

I have Spring + JPA(Hibernate) web-application.

Context configuration (data-context.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myapp.mvc.logic.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.mvc.logic" />
```

DispetcherServlet configuration (servlet-context.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    ">      

<annotation-driven validator="validator"/>

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<default-servlet-handler/>  

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</beans:value>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
</interceptors> 

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
            id="messageSource"
            p:basenames="classpath:META-INF/i18n/application, classpath:META-INF/i18n/validation_messages"
            />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
            id="localeResolver"
            p:cookieName="locale"/>

<beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.mvc" />
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Controller
public class BankAccountCatalogController {

@Inject
private Functions functions;

@RequestMapping(value="/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String catalogBankAccountUpdate(Model uiModel) {
    functions.addUser();
    return "employee_cabinet/catalog_bank_account";
}
}
```

Functions.class:

```
@Service("functions")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class Functions {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void addUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("John");
    user.setLastName("John");
    user.setMiddleName("John");
    user.setEmail("John@gmail.com");
    user.setPhone(null);
    user.setMd5Password("1234");
    em.persist(user);
    em.flush();
}
}
```

When I activate the controller, in `em.flush();` line I get an error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

On some reason transaction don't active in `addUser()` function. I tried run function in JUnit environment - it works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272354/why-do-we-have-to-manually-flush-the-entitymanager-in-a-extended-persistenceco#

Comment: @Baadshah How could it help in my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was wrong configuration of DispetcherServlet.

Instead of

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.mvc" />
```

in servlet-context.xml, I wrote

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.mvc.web.controller" />
```

and it works.

Helpful topic: [Spring @Transactional - javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220125/spring-transactional-javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `EntityManager` from the controller and specifying the method as transactional on the controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Controller
public class BankAccountCatalogController {

@Inject
private Functions functions;

@RequestMapping(value="/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional
public String catalogBankAccountUpdate(Model uiModel) {
    functions.addUser();
    return "employee_cabinet/catalog_bank_account";
}
}
```

Also make sure the `Functions` class is specified in the packages you are component scanning, which is `com.dominform.mvc.logic`.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dominform.mvc.logic" />
```